# Cannot open server in Centos 7 after insert DROP in Iptables(Connection timed out)

Tags: centos, iptables

I accidentally inserted DROP ALL in iptables when i tried to configure something. This caused my server cannot be open at all and show error'Connection Timed Out' and i dont know what to do since i am beginner in this. Please help me and i'll be very thankful for anyone who helped me.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot comment sorry!

The only thing you can do is reboot it from the console or front power switch. (or ask the company where its hosted etc).  In iptables if you didn't save the changes it will probably revert to the last iptables you had before you had the errors.  Always ssh into the server after changes in iptables prior to closing the terminal you are working in to test that you can still get in.  If iptables is dropping all you have no choice but to try reboot and hope you didn't save it.  If you have access to the console, keyboard and monitor of the system you could repair it from there.

You need to tell us is it a virtual machine, a hosted server, etc?

Comment: that looks like an answer to me

Comment: I didnt edit the configuration file directly but i think ive use echo and maybe the file has been saved..im using ssh client such as Termius, not vm.